# rebuild Json List

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```js
// Start with this JSON
var initialJson = {
  "rows": [{
    "ID": 123,
    "Data": 430910,
    "VersionNum": 0,
    "RowSeqNum": 1,
    "IterationNum": 1,
    "FirstName": "Aqwemara",
    "LastName": "Seweqweebi",
    "Location": "CweAN",
    "Role": "Site",
    "In_Out": "Internal",
    "Editor": "User1",
    "Edit_Date": "2015%2D02%2D25T15%3A30%3A47%2E883Z"
  }]
};


//Create an array that lists the Keys for the NEW JSON
var hResponse = [];
hResponse.push("FirstName", "LastName", "Location", "Role", "Editor", "Edit_Date");
var wbuResponse = [];

// When GO! button is pressed,  process the "initialJson" object, creating a new object with only the Keys listed in "hResponse" array
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.btn').click(function() {
         
        wbuResponse.push(
            for each(hHeading in hResponse[{
              hHeading: response[i].hHeading
            }]);

            console.log(JSON.stringify(wbuResponse));
          });
      });












    //console setup 
    var consoleLine = "<p class=\"console-line\"></p>";

    console = {
      log: function(text) {
        $("#console-log").append($(consoleLine).html(text));
      }
    };
```

```css
.console-line {
  font-family: console;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="btn" type="button" id="btn" value="Go!">
<div id="console-log"></div>
```

I want to take the `initialJson` , I will modify the pairs, then rebuild the JSON based on the entries in the `hResponse` array.

Focusing on the rebuild part, I only want to take a certain amount of the keys and put them into the new JSON array.

Can i do a for each loop within the `wbuResponse.push` to create the correct structure? 
Am I doing this right, maybe there is a better more efficient way?

Thanks

JSFIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/b5m0nk67/5/

Comment: copy the relevant parts of the code into the question , please.

Comment: I have done, is JSFiddle insufficient?

Comment: jumping around between links to code and question isn't what people want to do over here ...

Comment: what is this `for each(hHeading in hResponse[{ ...` thingy doing? That's causing a syntax error?

Comment: Axel, im afraid that is my badly crafted theory, I know this will work : 
wbuResponse.push([{"FirstName": response[i].FirstName, "LastName":response[i].LastName}]);

but I want to automate the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called map. It's a built-in function in modern JavaScript implementations: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Using `.map()`, your filtering code could look something like this:

```
var wbuResponse = initalJson.map(function(row, index) {
  return {
    FirstName: row.FirstName,
    LastName: row.LastName,
    Location: row.Location,
    Role: row.Role,
    Editor: row.Editor,
    Edit_Date: row.Edit_Date
  };
});
```

If you wanted to use an approach like the one you're alluding to, with an array of property names to filter down to rather than having it hard-coded, you could do something like this:

```
var props = ["FirstName", "LastName", "Location", "Role", "Editor", "Edit_Date"];

var wbuResponse = initalJson.map(function(row, index) {
  var mappedRow = { };

  for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
    mappedRow[props[i]] = row[props[i]];
  }

  return mappedRow;
});
```

For broader browser support, you can use jQuery's built-in map function that includes a polyfill for browsers that don't support it natively. A few examples of that here: http://encosia.com/use-jquery-to-extract-data-from-html-lists-and-tables/

Comment: Nail on the head. Thanks!

Comment: @platinums: Great. Glad I could help. Also check out the other list comprehensions like reduce and filter, while you're at it. That approach to dealing with arrays can be very powerful, performant, and expressive, with minimal coding on your part.